# wordpress - front end css applied in admin panel

Tags: css, wordpress

I am working on a plugin which loads its own css for front end and it is working fine. But the same css is also being applied for admin dashboard. i want to prevent the plugin css loading in admin dashboard.
I have registered the css styles and enqeued prpperly to `init` but not able to understand what is causing the css to be loaded inside admin dashboard.
Below is the code I used to register and enqeue the stylesheet.

```
function skillapp_css(){
 wp_register_style('sh_css', plugins_url('assets/css/styles.css', __FILE__), false, 1.1);
 wp_enqueue_style('sh_css');}add_action('init', 'skillapp_css');
```

Answer (score 3):

You're hooking too early. For styles and scripts you should be hooking to `wp_enqueue_scripts` for front end resources or `admin_enqueue_scripts` for admin resources.

```
function skillapp_css(){
    wp_register_style('sh_css', plugins_url('assets/css/styles.css', __FILE__), false, 1.1);
    wp_enqueue_style('sh_css');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'skillapp_css' );
```

Comment: That's better. Thanks!